# Prove: $a+b+c \ge \frac{3}{2}$ and $a^2 + b + c^2 \ge 1$

Tags: inequality

> If $a,b,c ≥ 0$ and $ab+bc+ca+2abc=1$, prove that $$a+b+c ≥ 3/2$$ and $$a^2 + b + c^2 ≥ 1$$

I tried using the expansion of $(a+b+c)^2$ and $a^3+b^3+c^3$, but nothing helped.

Any hints$?$

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! [It is advisable that you take a tour to see what we are about](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour). Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959)'s a quick guide (if nothing else, read up the part on "[avoiding no-clue questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/#27933)").

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: “*I have no ideas about this problem*.“ It’s a pity because it means that the question would soon get closed most probably.

Comment: If I am not wrong, the minimum value of $\sum_{cyc}a^2$ is coming out to be $3/4$ and not $1$

Comment: The problem is wrong, it's need to be $a^2 + b + c^2 ≥ 1$, sorry

Answer (score 2):

Apply the AM-GM property on the constraint given $$\frac{ab+bc+ca+2abc}{4}\ge\sqrt[4]{ab\cdot bc\cdot ca\cdot 2abc}$$ $$\implies abc\le\frac18$$

Now apply AM-GM on $a+b+c$ $$\frac{a+b+c}3\ge\sqrt[3]{abc}$$ $$\implies a+b+c\ge\frac32$$

I hope you can prove the other one yourself.

**Edit:**

You can prove the 2nd statement by applying AM-GM on $a^2+b+c^2$ after rewriting it as $a^2+b/2+b/2+c^2$

Comment: This solution is flawed. I agree that you have shown $ abc \leq 1/8$ and $ abc \leq [(a+b+c)/3 ]^3$. However, note that this doesn't allow you to conclude that $ 1/8 \leq [(a+b+c)/3 ]^3$ OR $[(a+b+c)/3 ]^3 \leq 1/8$. $\quad$ I downvoted, and do not understand the 3 upvotes, esp for a poorly asked question.

Comment: @CalvinLin the maximum value of $abc$ is $\frac18$ and $[(a+b+c)/3]^3$ is greater than or equal to $abc$ for any value of $a$,$b$ and $c$. So it must be greater than or equal to it's max value too

Comment: If $ f(x) \leq 1/8 $ and $f(x) \leq g(x)$, how do you reason out that $ 1/8 \leq g(x)$?  $\quad$ In particular, note that $ f(x) \leq 100$ and $f(x) \leq g(x)$, so are you going to conclude that $100 \leq g(x)$ too? $\quad$ As another example, $ f(x) =  -x^2 \leq 0 $ and $f(x) =  -x^2  \leq - x^2/2 = g(x) $. So are you concluding that $ 0 \leq - x^2$?

Comment: @CalvinLin I understood

Comment: But, so how will we do it?

Comment: You could post it as a question and show your work, and maybe it won't be closed.

Comment: As a hint: Let $   S  = a+b+c$. By applying AM-GM,  find a polynomial inequality in terms of $S$ only, and hence conclude that $ S \geq 3/2$. $\quad$ Please update your solution to reflect the above, thanks.